# gradle Lint plugin defined task for include or exclude custom files

Tags: gradle, android-lint, gradle-task

I am using gradle lint plugin in my Android project on CI Server. But sometimes I want to run android lint only on custom files, just like gradle `Copy` Task `include` and `exclude` to defined task scope in my gradle task.

In Android Studio, inspection can defined these behavior. But in my case, it is gradle task run on CI Server without UI interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the Gradle Plugin is capeable of that. However you can also run `lint` on it's own.

`lint [flags] <project directory>`

You can get all of the options with:

`lint --help`

The executable is located in `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/`

[More information here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#standalone-lint).

Comment: You are right. The Gradle Plugin is not capable of that. What I am trying to do is to use custom lint for a huge project. But still didn't find a great way to approach that